# How to delete rows from a dataframe that contain n*NA

Tags: r, filter, merge, rows, na

I have a number of large datasets with ~10 columns, and ~200000 rows. Not all columns contain values for each row, although at least one column must contain a value for the row to be present, I would like to set a threshold for how many `NA`s are allowed in a row.

My Dataframe looks something like this:

```
 ID q  r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z
 A  1  5  NA 3  8  9  NA 8  6  4
 B  5  NA 4  6  1  9  7  4  9  3 
 C  NA 9  4  NA 4  8  4  NA 5  NA
 D  2  2  6  8  4  NA 3  7  1  32
```

And I would like to be able to delete the rows that contain more than 2 cells containing NA to get

```
ID q  r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z
 A 1  5  NA 3  8  9  NA 8  6  4
 B 5  NA 4  6  1  9  7  4  9  3 
 D 2  2  6  8  4  NA 3  7  1  32
```

`complete.cases` removes all rows containing any `NA`, and I know one can delete rows that contain `NA` in certain columns but is there a way to modify it so that it is non-specific about which columns contain `NA`, but how many of the total do?

Alternatively, this dataframe is generated by merging several dataframes using

```
    file1<-read.delim("~/file1.txt")
    file2<-read.delim(file=args[1])

    file1<-merge(file1,file2,by="chr.pos",all=TRUE)
```

Perhaps the merge function could be altered?

Thanks

Answer (score 17):

Use `rowSums`. To remove rows from a data frame (`df`) that contain precisely *n* `NA` values:

```
df <- df[rowSums(is.na(df)) != n, ]
```

or to remove rows that contain *n* or more `NA` values:

```
df <- df[rowSums(is.na(df)) < n, ]
```

in both cases of course replacing `n` with the number that's required

Comment: +1 for the use of `n`.  You might want to explain what n is meant to represent though.

Comment: This generates a new column named `row.names` in `df`, why is that? This is one of the R phenomena that I just do not understand. Sometimes functions output extra stuff that I don' t expect.

Answer (score 4):

If `dat` is the name of your data.frame the following will return what you're looking for:

```
keep <- rowSums(is.na(dat)) < 2
dat <- dat[keep, ]
```

### What this is doing:

```
is.na(dat) 
# returns a matrix of T/F
# note that when adding logicals 
# T == 1, and F == 0

rowSums(.)
# quickly computes the total per row 
# since your task is to identify the
# rows with a certain number of NA's 

rowSums(.) < 2 
# for each row, determine if the sum 
# (which is the number of NAs) is less
# than 2 or not.  Returns T/F accordingly
```

We use the output of this last statement to
identify which rows to keep.  Note that it is not necessary to actually store this last logical.

Answer (score 2):

If `d` is your data frame, try this:

```
d <- d[rowSums(is.na(d)) < 2,]
```

Answer (score 1):

This will return a dataset where at most two values per row are missing:

```
dfrm[ apply(dfrm, 1, function(r) sum(is.na(x)) <= 2 ) , ]
```