# Remove all rows tha contain values below 0.10 (in all row) in R

Tags: r, apply

This is my matrix:

```
x<-structure(list(Sample_250 = list(`ITUB4~time+ITSA4` = 0.0189772705000679, 
    `ITSA4~time+ITUB4` = 0.0172247829378391, `KROT3~time+ESTC3` = 0.362976295896543, 
    `ESTC3~time+KROT3` = 0.919654541750147, `ELET6~time+ELET3` = 0.563149047013394, 
    `ELET3~time+ELET6` = 0.938978962441099, `VALE5~time+BRAP4` = 0.00879735041567956, 
    `BRAP4~time+VALE5` = 0.00327639807633581, `RSID3~time+PDGR3` = 0.537991430220927, 
    `PDGR3~time+RSID3` = 0.246554103682342, `PDGR3~time+BISA3` = 0.559254391144534, 
    `BISA3~time+PDGR3` = 0.61031816244403, `VALE5~time+VALE3` = 0.180842743583616, 
    `VALE3~time+VALE5` = 0.66647273985911, `BRPR3~time+BRML3` = 0.338499489464644, 
    `BRML3~time+BRPR3` = 0.319063657443075, `PETR4~time+PETR3` = 0.125540460125629, 
    `PETR3~time+PETR4` = 0.124801328997536, `DTEX3~time+CSAN3` = 0.93868928574058, 
    `CSAN3~time+DTEX3` = 0.237699406950144, `RSID3~time+BISA3` = 0.449718913669525, 
    `BISA3~time+RSID3` = 0.7561632200477, `ELPL4~time+ELET3` = 0.174294574975377, 
    `ELET3~time+ELPL4` = 0.300066723578605, `EVEN3~time+CSAN3` = 0.734452997271797, 
    `CSAN3~time+EVEN3` = 0.104402290451259, `KROT3~time+CIEL3` = 0.93683315998679, 
    `CIEL3~time+KROT3` = 0.936544198858508, `MRFG3~time+BISA3` = 0.588077047082012, 
    `BISA3~time+MRFG3` = 0.241408284405396), Sample_220 = list(
    `ITUB4~time+ITSA4` = 0.0173697888550166, `ITSA4~time+ITUB4` = 0.0149942952128483, 
    `KROT3~time+ESTC3` = 0.482794731209648, `ESTC3~time+KROT3` = 0.890472799194387, 
    `ELET6~time+ELET3` = 0.289262231792853, `ELET3~time+ELET6` = 0.583772170805346, 
    `VALE5~time+BRAP4` = 0.0115132699560557, `BRAP4~time+VALE5` = 0.00454387128721931, 
    `RSID3~time+PDGR3` = 0.701361295124465, `PDGR3~time+RSID3` = 0.276392398580336, 
    `PDGR3~time+BISA3` = 0.459917895151059, `BISA3~time+PDGR3` = 0.932334809205404, 
    `VALE5~time+VALE3` = 0.228621489426817, `VALE3~time+VALE5` = 0.599616896543261, 
    `BRPR3~time+BRML3` = 0.423214373690621, `BRML3~time+BRPR3` = 0.43367402957197, 
    `PETR4~time+PETR3` = 0.0726218638061883, `PETR3~time+PETR4` = 0.0684556705423691, 
    `DTEX3~time+CSAN3` = 0.957213428702438, `CSAN3~time+DTEX3` = 0.643249328242026, 
    `RSID3~time+BISA3` = 0.140702283930701, `BISA3~time+RSID3` = 0.438759561659429, 
    `ELPL4~time+ELET3` = 0.108415504373493, `ELET3~time+ELPL4` = 0.259235741006097, 
    `EVEN3~time+CSAN3` = 0.995097190780355, `CSAN3~time+EVEN3` = 0.35833286961364, 
    `KROT3~time+CIEL3` = 0.883381800410008, `CIEL3~time+KROT3` = 0.58096328992918, 
    `MRFG3~time+BISA3` = 0.811273794794714, `BISA3~time+MRFG3` = 0.162511686203042), 
    Sample_200 = list(`ITUB4~time+ITSA4` = 0.0269410475431228, 
        `ITSA4~time+ITUB4` = 0.0268281043283851, `KROT3~time+ESTC3` = 0.648973944293657, 
        `ESTC3~time+KROT3` = 0.843925839073412, `ELET6~time+ELET3` = 0.85074648265282, 
        `ELET3~time+ELET6` = 0.926090646237098, `VALE5~time+BRAP4` = 0.0298988391464108, 
        `BRAP4~time+VALE5` = 0.0210534678726486, `RSID3~time+PDGR3` = 0.913261323047721, 
        `PDGR3~time+RSID3` = 0.460744060168818, `PDGR3~time+BISA3` = 0.681848278084124, 
        `BISA3~time+PDGR3` = 0.700508228924671, `VALE5~time+VALE3` = 0.404824931817606, 
        `VALE3~time+VALE5` = 0.858492744479535, `BRPR3~time+BRML3` = 0.282313695830455, 
        `BRML3~time+BRPR3` = 0.421361074266136, `PETR4~time+PETR3` = 0.0389941410401918, 
        `PETR3~time+PETR4` = 0.0366363568643157, `DTEX3~time+CSAN3` = 0.593381022274927, 
        `CSAN3~time+DTEX3` = 0.296186622367649, `RSID3~time+BISA3` = 0.136337062156413, 
        `BISA3~time+RSID3` = 0.253647313739565, `ELPL4~time+ELET3` = 0.0404140463603602, 
        `ELET3~time+ELPL4` = 0.0584026420525388, `EVEN3~time+CSAN3` = 0.992224496682121, 
        `CSAN3~time+EVEN3` = 0.364016491282029, `KROT3~time+CIEL3` = 0.923443434909376, 
        `CIEL3~time+KROT3` = 0.492267643047159, `MRFG3~time+BISA3` = 0.505439622239642, 
        `BISA3~time+MRFG3` = 0.433741779126583), Sample_180 = list(
        `ITUB4~time+ITSA4` = 0.0709729806619366, `ITSA4~time+ITUB4` = 0.0703318148854131, 
        `KROT3~time+ESTC3` = 0.714222637099451, `ESTC3~time+KROT3` = 0.983192555139107, 
        `ELET6~time+ELET3` = 0.651446390753224, `ELET3~time+ELET6` = 0.504251519490735, 
        `VALE5~time+BRAP4` = 0.0655201102796135, `BRAP4~time+VALE5` = 0.064459649024225, 
        `RSID3~time+PDGR3` = 0.966515813873172, `PDGR3~time+RSID3` = 0.353225059948276, 
        `PDGR3~time+BISA3` = 0.819582167704402, `BISA3~time+PDGR3` = 0.457403474593761, 
        `VALE5~time+VALE3` = 0.834891076683459, `VALE3~time+VALE5` = 0.624305154223115, 
        `BRPR3~time+BRML3` = 0.338684631277372, `BRML3~time+BRPR3` = 0.645983354906404, 
        `PETR4~time+PETR3` = 0.016615774081754, `PETR3~time+PETR4` = 0.0165629129043023, 
        `DTEX3~time+CSAN3` = 0.642061011299162, `CSAN3~time+DTEX3` = 0.424690135396935, 
        `RSID3~time+BISA3` = 0.101897354576195, `BISA3~time+RSID3` = 0.204241392846169, 
        `ELPL4~time+ELET3` = 0.0729734425567139, `ELET3~time+ELPL4` = 0.128996393897499, 
        `EVEN3~time+CSAN3` = 0.899884399768484, `CSAN3~time+EVEN3` = 0.146722568327017, 
        `KROT3~time+CIEL3` = 0.830125914939971, `CIEL3~time+KROT3` = 0.567087012782755, 
        `MRFG3~time+BISA3` = 0.122725171728208, `BISA3~time+MRFG3` = 0.459448430490008)), row.names = c("ITUB4~time+ITSA4", 
"ITSA4~time+ITUB4", "KROT3~time+ESTC3", "ESTC3~time+KROT3", "ELET6~time+ELET3", 
"ELET3~time+ELET6", "VALE5~time+BRAP4", "BRAP4~time+VALE5", "RSID3~time+PDGR3", 
"PDGR3~time+RSID3", "PDGR3~time+BISA3", "BISA3~time+PDGR3", "VALE5~time+VALE3", 
"VALE3~time+VALE5", "BRPR3~time+BRML3", "BRML3~time+BRPR3", "PETR4~time+PETR3", 
"PETR3~time+PETR4", "DTEX3~time+CSAN3", "CSAN3~time+DTEX3", "RSID3~time+BISA3", 
"BISA3~time+RSID3", "ELPL4~time+ELET3", "ELET3~time+ELPL4", "EVEN3~time+CSAN3", 
"CSAN3~time+EVEN3", "KROT3~time+CIEL3", "CIEL3~time+KROT3", "MRFG3~time+BISA3", 
"BISA3~time+MRFG3"), class = "data.frame")
```

1º Question) I want to remove all rows that contain values bellow 0.10. It is necessary that values bellow 0.10 belongs for the 4 columns

2º Question) I want to remove all rows that contain values bellow 0.10 on the first 3 columns.

I tried this:

```
x[x[1:nrow(x),]<.10,]
```

Is it possible to do this with a basic function in R?

Any help ?

Thanks

Comment: You can use `df[rowSums(<condition 1 (what to look for)>) <condition 2 (how many)>]` as described e.g. here: [How to delete rows from a dataframe that contain n*NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18116305/how-to-delete-rows-from-a-dataframe-that-contain-nna)

Comment: It works for you @Henrik?

Comment: I haven't tried. I was just suggesting a commonly used (and fast) method for what I _thought_ was your question. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try for question 1 `x[!apply(x, 1, function(x) any(x < .10)), ]`

```
                 Sample_250 Sample_220 Sample_200 Sample_180
KROT3~time+ESTC3  0.3629763  0.4827947  0.6489739  0.7142226
ESTC3~time+KROT3  0.9196545  0.8904728  0.8439258  0.9831926
ELET6~time+ELET3   0.563149  0.2892622  0.8507465  0.6514464
ELET3~time+ELET6   0.938979  0.5837722  0.9260906  0.5042515
RSID3~time+PDGR3  0.5379914  0.7013613  0.9132613  0.9665158
PDGR3~time+RSID3  0.2465541  0.2763924  0.4607441  0.3532251
PDGR3~time+BISA3  0.5592544  0.4599179  0.6818483  0.8195822
BISA3~time+PDGR3  0.6103182  0.9323348  0.7005082  0.4574035
VALE5~time+VALE3  0.1808427  0.2286215  0.4048249  0.8348911
VALE3~time+VALE5  0.6664727  0.5996169  0.8584927  0.6243052
BRPR3~time+BRML3  0.3384995  0.4232144  0.2823137  0.3386846
BRML3~time+BRPR3  0.3190637   0.433674  0.4213611  0.6459834
DTEX3~time+CSAN3  0.9386893  0.9572134   0.593381   0.642061
CSAN3~time+DTEX3  0.2376994  0.6432493  0.2961866  0.4246901
RSID3~time+BISA3  0.4497189  0.1407023  0.1363371  0.1018974
BISA3~time+RSID3  0.7561632  0.4387596  0.2536473  0.2042414
EVEN3~time+CSAN3   0.734453  0.9950972  0.9922245  0.8998844
CSAN3~time+EVEN3  0.1044023  0.3583329  0.3640165  0.1467226
KROT3~time+CIEL3  0.9368332  0.8833818  0.9234434  0.8301259
CIEL3~time+KROT3  0.9365442  0.5809633  0.4922676   0.567087
MRFG3~time+BISA3   0.588077  0.8112738  0.5054396  0.1227252
BISA3~time+MRFG3  0.2414083  0.1625117  0.4337418  0.4594484
```

For question 2: `x[!apply(x[, 1:3], 1, function(x) any(x < .10)), ]`

```
                 Sample_250 Sample_220 Sample_200 Sample_180
KROT3~time+ESTC3  0.3629763  0.4827947  0.6489739  0.7142226
ESTC3~time+KROT3  0.9196545  0.8904728  0.8439258  0.9831926
ELET6~time+ELET3   0.563149  0.2892622  0.8507465  0.6514464
ELET3~time+ELET6   0.938979  0.5837722  0.9260906  0.5042515
RSID3~time+PDGR3  0.5379914  0.7013613  0.9132613  0.9665158
PDGR3~time+RSID3  0.2465541  0.2763924  0.4607441  0.3532251
PDGR3~time+BISA3  0.5592544  0.4599179  0.6818483  0.8195822
BISA3~time+PDGR3  0.6103182  0.9323348  0.7005082  0.4574035
VALE5~time+VALE3  0.1808427  0.2286215  0.4048249  0.8348911
VALE3~time+VALE5  0.6664727  0.5996169  0.8584927  0.6243052
BRPR3~time+BRML3  0.3384995  0.4232144  0.2823137  0.3386846
BRML3~time+BRPR3  0.3190637   0.433674  0.4213611  0.6459834
DTEX3~time+CSAN3  0.9386893  0.9572134   0.593381   0.642061
CSAN3~time+DTEX3  0.2376994  0.6432493  0.2961866  0.4246901
RSID3~time+BISA3  0.4497189  0.1407023  0.1363371  0.1018974
BISA3~time+RSID3  0.7561632  0.4387596  0.2536473  0.2042414
EVEN3~time+CSAN3   0.734453  0.9950972  0.9922245  0.8998844
CSAN3~time+EVEN3  0.1044023  0.3583329  0.3640165  0.1467226
KROT3~time+CIEL3  0.9368332  0.8833818  0.9234434  0.8301259
CIEL3~time+KROT3  0.9365442  0.5809633  0.4922676   0.567087
MRFG3~time+BISA3   0.588077  0.8112738  0.5054396  0.1227252
BISA3~time+MRFG3  0.2414083  0.1625117  0.4337418  0.4594484
```

Comment: Sorry you want `any`, not `all`

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

In regards to question 1:

```
cond1 <- apply(x[,1:3] < 0.1, 1, any) 
y <- x[!cond1, ]
head(x)
#                 Sample_250 Sample_220 Sample_200 Sample_180
#ITUB4~time+ITSA4 0.01897727 0.01736979 0.02694105 0.07097298
#ITSA4~time+ITUB4 0.01722478  0.0149943  0.0268281 0.07033181
#KROT3~time+ESTC3  0.3629763  0.4827947  0.6489739  0.7142226
#ESTC3~time+KROT3  0.9196545  0.8904728  0.8439258  0.9831926
#ELET6~time+ELET3   0.563149  0.2892622  0.8507465  0.6514464
#ELET3~time+ELET6   0.938979  0.5837722  0.9260906  0.5042515
```

In regards to question 2:

```
cond2 <- apply(x < 0.1, 1, all)
z <- x[!cond2, ]
head(y)
#                 Sample_250 Sample_220 Sample_200 Sample_180
#ITUB4~time+ITSA4 0.01897727 0.01736979 0.02694105 0.07097298
#ITSA4~time+ITUB4 0.01722478  0.0149943  0.0268281 0.07033181
#KROT3~time+ESTC3  0.3629763  0.4827947  0.6489739  0.7142226
#ESTC3~time+KROT3  0.9196545  0.8904728  0.8439258  0.9831926
#ELET6~time+ELET3   0.563149  0.2892622  0.8507465  0.6514464
#ELET3~time+ELET6   0.938979  0.5837722  0.9260906  0.5042515
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first question:

```
subset(x, apply(x, 1, function(x) all(x > 0.1)) == TRUE)
```

For the second one:

```
subset(x, apply(x[, 1:3], 1, function(x) all(x > 0.1)) == TRUE)
```