# Get rid of consecutive na in columns of a matirx

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, data.table, na

I asked the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66032721/delete-missing-values-according-to-a-constraint-in-r?noredirect=1#comment116749437_66032721) but it was closed as my post has been associated with similar questions **although they are not related to my question and don't resolve it.**

**The dataset:**

I have a huge data set saved in a matrix where the number of rows is more that one million with a dozen of columns.

The matrix looks like

```
data <- matrix(c(1, NA, 2, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 3, NA, 5, NA, NA, NA, 8, NA, 5, NA, 7, NA, NA, NA), ncol=3)
> data
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    8
[2,]   NA   NA   NA
[3,]    2    3    5
[4,]   NA   NA   NA
[5,]    1    5    7
[6,]   NA   NA   NA
[7,]   NA   NA   NA
[8,]   NA   NA   NA
```

So if there is a missing value in certain column, then necessarily other columns will have missing values for the same row.

**The question:**

I would like to delete ***"efficiently"*** consecutive missing values if there are 3 or more in each column for all columns in the matrix. So I would like to delete **consecutive na in a column not a row.**

*I already saw solutions, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66032721/delete-missing-values-according-to-a-constraint-in-r?noredirect=1#comment116749437_66032721),  for my question but they were too slow for my huge data set. Do you have other suggestions which can achieve the objective efficiently? Additionally, the suggested answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862178/remove-rows-with-all-or-some-nas-missing-values-in-data-frame) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18116305/how-to-delete-rows-from-a-dataframe-that-contain-nna)) for my closed question are deleting if the missing values are consecutive in rows not columns.*

EDIT:

Following to the comment below, the output must be like this:

```
         [,1] [,2] [,3]
    [1,]    1    1    8
    [2,]   NA   NA   NA
    [3,]    2    3    5
    [4,]   NA   NA   NA
    [5,]    1    5    7
```

EDIT:

```
> data
         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
    [1,]    1    1    8    NA
    [2,]   NA   NA   NA    NA
    [3,]    2    3    5    NA
    [4,]   NA   NA   NA    NA
    [5,]    1    5    7    NA
    [6,]   NA   NA   NA    NA
    [7,]   NA   NA   NA    NA
    [8,]   NA   NA   NA    NA
```

The expected output

```
         [,1] [,2] [,3]
    [1,]    1    1    8
    [2,]   NA   NA   NA
    [3,]    2    3    5
    [4,]   NA   NA   NA
    [5,]    1    5    7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is consecutive, then may be `rle` can be used

```
i1 <- rowSums(is.na(data)) > 0
# // or just forgot to update here
i1 <- is.na(data[,1])

data[!inverse.rle(within.list(rle(i1), {
          values[values & lengths < 3] <- FALSE})),]
```

-output

```
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    1    8
#[2,]   NA   NA   NA
#[3,]    2    3    5
#[4,]   NA   NA   NA
#[5,]    1    5    7
```

#### Update

If we have a particular column with all `NA`s, then we can remove it first

```
data1 <- data[,colSums(!is.na(data)) != 0]
```

and now we apply the previous code on the selected column data

```
i1 <- is.na(data1[,1])

data1[!inverse.rle(within.list(rle(i1), {
      values[values & lengths < 3] <- FALSE})),]
```

---

Or we may use `rleid` from `data.table` (which would be more efficient)

```
library(data.table)
data[as.data.table(data)[, .I[!(.N >=3 & is.na(V1))], 
             rleid(is.na(V1))]$V1,]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you think that this could be the most efficient method for a data set of millions?

Comment: @Jean I saw your update expected after I posted the answer.  Initially, it was looping over the rows with `apply`.  Now, with your condition that a row can be all NA if any of the row is NA, then either select the first and check for NA with `is.na` or use `rowSums` on is.na.  apply the `rle` on the logical vector to subset the data based on the `lengths` condition

Comment: Thanks for your updates. What if there is only one column which contains consecutive missing values and other columns not?

Comment: @Jean In that case, what is your expected output?  i.e. are you looking for an `OR` condition or `AND` here i.e. all the columns should have consecutive NAs, then remove it?

Comment: Yes you are right, effectivly, all columns must contain NAs in the same rows. On the other hand, I am trying to modify your script to include a more general case where there is an additional column contains consecutive NAs regardless the values in other columns. I will add an update for this general case.

Answer (score 2):

> if there is a missing value in certain column, then necessarily other columns will have missing values for the same row.

I think this is very important information, we can take advantage of it and work only with any 1 column instead of complete dataset. Try :

```
vec <- data[, 1]
data[!with(rle(is.na(vec)), rep(values & lengths >= 3, lengths)), ]

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    1    8
#[2,]   NA   NA   NA
#[3,]    2    3    5
#[4,]   NA   NA   NA
#[5,]    1    5    7
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this answer archived the objective also.